# How does collectd secure data?

Tags: security, encryption, credentials, sign, collectd

I like to transmit data from multiple sources to one target collectd server, but I'm not sure, how to ensure, that at the same time:

1. data is encrypted, i.e. no need to trust the network
2. data is signed, i.e. the target can trust the sources
3. no source shares the credentials with other sources

However, in the `network` plugin, so far I found only the values `sign` or `encrypt` for `SecurityLevel`, but not both. And it seems, that I cannot have different credentials (`Username` + `Password`) for different sources. Maybe I just misunderstood collectd?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 questions.

**1) Encryption vs. signing**

- `SecurityLevel "sign"` provides sender verification.
- `SecurityLevel "encrypt"` provides both encryption and sender verification.

In private/public keys schemes signing and encryption are separate: you can sign without encrypting, or encrypt without signing. However collectd uses a shared-secret scheme: both encryption and signing guarantee that the sender knows the shared secret: the sender is always verified.

**2) Multiple credentials**

You can have different credentials for different sources. See the following sample configuration.

```
<Plugin "network">
  <Listen "192.168.0.1">
    SecurityLevel "Encrypt"
    AuthFile "/etc/collectd/auth_file"
  </Listen>
</Plugin>
```

Where `/etc/collectd/auth_file` contains credentials using the following format.

```
user1: password1
user2: password2
```

References: https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php?title=Networking_introduction